# When I open new layouts, the menu item duplicates

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio, menuitem

I'm learning how to create an app and have figured out how to build a login activity and a menu for logging out that returns you to the login layout. However, if I navigate through my different layouts/activities, the menu item for logging out duplicates. I believe it's due to having the menu created on each layout, but I'm not sure how to change it so that it doesn't duplicate.

Here's my fragment.

```
    public class UserFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle
        savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_user_fragment, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_logout, menu);
}
}
```

My LoginActivity.class

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    Button b1login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btlogin);
    Button b2login_cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btcancel_login);

    assert b1login != null;
    b1login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etuser_name);
            EditText ed2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etpassword);
            if (ed1.getText().toString().equals(getText(R.string.user_id)) &&
                    ed2.getText().toString().equals(getText(R.string.user_password))) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.successful_login,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_clients);


            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.unsuccessful_login,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    assert b2login_cancel != null;
    b2login_cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
}

//Menu option logout return to login screen.
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.menu_item_logout) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        this.startActivity(i);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



public void addClient(View view) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_client);
}

public void submitClient(View view) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sessions);
}

public void cancelClient(View view) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_clients);
}


public void newSession(View view) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_session);
}

public void cancelSessionCompletion(View view) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sessions);
}

public void cancelSession(View view) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sessions);
}
}
```

Fragment layout.

```
<menu
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_item_logout"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_logout"
    android:title="@string/logout"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
</menu
```

EDIT:

I deleted the fragment where I initially created the menu as well as the menu code from the UserFragment and hard coded the menu itself into the LoginActivity class, which fixed the duplication issue.

Code adding menu.

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
    }
```

However, the menu now shows on the login screen. How do I prevent it from showing there?

Comment: Yeah am sure you don't want any Logout menu in your LoginActivity because at that moment, the user is not even logged In?

Comment: The menu doesn't show on the login screen because I have it set to load with the fragment that displays the user's username when logged in.

Comment: Now that I've fixed the duplication issue, it's showing on the login screen. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For having different menu items in different activities you need to create different menu xml layouts.

So one file named menu.xml is already there in res folder. You need to create new xml file in same folder.

Then in java code of that activity :-  in override Oncreateoptionmenu  inflate the menu you want.

Comment: I want the same menu item (logout) displayed in all of the activities. What's happening is when I load new layouts, the menu is being duplicated.

Comment: Then in all those activities where you want to display same menu , just change inflate.inflate (in OnCreateOptionMenu) item to same xml file name.

Comment: Please do let me know if I am not getting your question in right way.

Comment: I fixed the duplication issue. The fragment was causing the menu to be recreated on each layout call. However, the menu now shows on the login screen. Any ideas on preventing it from showing?

Comment: Alright Ankesh your answer worked. My issue was my lack of understanding the relationship between multiple layouts and classes. I had just the initial LoginActivity.class doing all of the work, which caused my initial post's issue, among other complications. I created a couple new classes and threw in some intents and then did what you said. That fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need to do:

- In your LoginActivity class, you want to NOT inflate the menu because you don't want users to do see the logout option.
- In your Activity that loads after Login, you actually want to inflate the Logout menu - well, because you want them to see and use that option.

In your code, I see that your fragment uses the method :

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

What you can do here is use an if statement to see if a user has logged in before and if not, set that to true otherwise, do nothing (which  is like setting to false).

You can reuse the menu in other activities if you want to enable users to Logout from those activities or just leave them it out!

I hope this helps!

**EDIT**

According to your sample code above, your first part shows what you would do inside a Fragment class - you setHasOptionsMenu(true). Now, it seems that you have two logout menus, in the activity and in the fragment - which I do not see where you have used your Fragment in your LoginActivity - unless it is somewhere else in a different activity!

Comment: I think your Activity is reusing  a fragment maybe?

Comment: I have the fragment set to display the user's username, so maybe it's being recreated with each new layout and duplicates the menu? Would it be better to have my buttons start an intent and run an actual new activity that set's up it's layout instead of having the buttons call layouts themselves?

Comment: Correct, my fragment is coded into the xml of my other layouts.

Comment: Alright, I fixed the duplication issue. The fragment was duplicating the menu on each layout call. However, I need to hide the menu from showing on the login screen. Any ideas?

Comment: Inside your LoginActivity, basically remove the optionsMenu code and you will not see the menu;

Comment: If I do that, it removes it from my other layouts as well.

Comment: i wish I could take a look at your code because I think there are other files you didn't share

Comment: I figured out my issue. This is my first android studio project and I was writing all of my code in the initial LoginActivity.class. I created a couple more classes with intents and did what Ankesh said in his answer. That did the trick. The issue was my lack of knowledge in using multiple classes and layouts together.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to my answer here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/63008005/5916188, a work-around would be to remove the menu each time, if it exists, before adding it.

Note that the existing menu is removed item by item (R.id...) while the inflated one is added by menu (R.menu...) as usual.

This way, you can keep the menu in the fragment. Like this:

```
    @Override public void onCreateOptionsMenu (@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater
        inflater)
{
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu (menu, inflater);

    removeMenuItemIfPresent (menu, R.id.menu_search_options);
    removeMenuItemIfPresent (menu, R.id.menu_sample_filter1);
    removeMenuItemIfPresent (menu, R.id.menu_sample_filter2);

    inflater.inflate (R.menu.menu_search_menu, menu);        
}

private void removeMenuItemIfPresent (@NonNull Menu menu, int resourceIDToRemove)
{
        MenuItem menuItemToRemove = menu.findItem (resourceIDToRemove);

        if (menuItemToRemove != null) {
            menu.removeItem (menuItemToRemove.getItemId ());
    }
}
```